# Using SASS syntax with gulp on visual studio code

Tags: visual-studio, sass, gulp, visual-studio-code

I installed SASS on visual studio code, but only works with the scss syntax.
file.scss are not recognized by the VS code ( when I use the classic indented syntax of sass).

Is there something in the gulpfile.js that i have to change?

Comment: What's your exact file ending? It must be .scss not .sass  #edit Here's a complete Web Project with gulp, sass typescript and handlebars https://github.com/geilix10/Blank-WebApp (Works all in VSCode)

Comment: Thanks for the data, I will edit the post, I didn't mean to talk about the extension, What I wanted to talk about was about compiling the sass code, when I am using the indented (classic sass) syntax. and not the scss syntax. I will explore this project to try to find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an extension that handles .sass files, like

> [Sass extension from vscode marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=robinbentley.sass-indented)

They are others as well.